# What SQL statement can I run in Rails console to describe table constraints/foreign keys?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I'm building a Rails application in an AWS Cloud9 environment. It's database is provided by the `sqlite3` gem.

I'm in my Rails console and trying to run an SQL query to describe a specific table. I think something went wrong with a migration and my schema is incorrect, and I want to examine the constraints/foreign keys in the underlying database table.

I've tried running: `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("desc resorts;")` but it gives me a `SQLite3::SQLException syntax error`.

I've tried it with and without the `;` and with upper and lowercase `desc`. I've tried `describe`, `describe table` and a few other things I've found in various articles, but nothing seems to work.

I believe the syntax of my method call is correct because this works fine for me: `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("select * from resorts;")`

Is there an SQL statement I can use that will show me the information about the constraints/foreign keys in that table?

Comment: Instead of using the console, why not just connect to the database directly with `rails db` and run your query there?

Comment: Thanks Jon!  Just tried that and it was much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at [the documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang.html), you'll see there is no `DESC` or `DESCRIBE` command in sqlite.

To list foreign keys used in a particular table, you can use [`PRAGMA foreign_key_list(tablename)`](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_foreign_key_list).

To list unique indexes and constraints, you can use the table valued function form of [`PRAGMA index_list(tablename)`](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_index_list):

```
SELECT * FROM pragma_index_list('tablename') WHERE "unique" = 1;
```

To list `NOT NULL` columns, you can use the table valued function form of [`PRAGMA table_info(tablename)`](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_table_info):

```
SELECT * FROM pragma_table_info('tablename') WHERE "notnull" = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you Shawn.